# Generator expression must be parenthesized on a constraint in gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I am currently working on an optimization project in gurobi.

I tried to add this constraint:

```py
for r in range(1, n_machines):
    for i in range(1, n_jobs):
        m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(max((c[r, j] - due_dates[speed][r, j]) for j in range(n_machines), 0 ) <= total_tardiness[i]))
```

But I always get the following error code:
**SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized**

Can you help me how to fix this?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: remove the `)` in `due_dates[speed][r, j])` and add it to the end of your generator e.g. `(c[r, j] - due_dates[speed][r, j] for j in range(n_machines))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to choose the max num with function max()

but `max()` gets params like `max([a, b, c, ...])` or `max(a, b, c, ...)`

your param is `max(Generator, other_number)`

it works if use `*` before the list.

the right code:

```
max(*((c[r, j] - due_dates[speed][r, j]) for j in range(n_machines)), 0 )
```

or

```
max(*[(c[r, j] - due_dates[speed][r, j]) for j in range(n_machines)], 0 )
```